# How to use host groups in Ansible effectively

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am writing a ansible script for my deployment and stuck at one problem. I have 6 tomcat nodes where I have do a rolling deployment i.e. first deploy on 3 nodes and test it. If the test is successful then go for remaining 3 nodes.
My current inventory looks like this -

```
[prod]
prod-1-myapp
prod-2-myapp
prod-3-myapp
prod-4-myapp
prod-5-myapp
prod-6-myapp

[preprod]
preprod-cn-p1
```

And I am using group_vars where I have `prod.yml/preprod.yml` to upload the configuration at run time.
Is it possible to segregate this host group into 2 and deploy on each of them accordingly.
If i create 2 host groups like below, how do i make use of my `prod.yml` at run time. How will it work?

```
[prod-1]
prod-1-myapp
prod-2-myapp
prod-3-myapp

[prod-2]
prod-4-myapp
prod-5-myapp
prod-6-myapp

[preprod]
preprod-cn-p1
```

My Current query -

```
ansible-playbook myapp-main.yml -e myapp_release_version=5.0.0 -e target_env=prod
```

**myapp-main.yml**

```
---
 - name: Starting with  Myapp Application deployment to tomcat nodes
   hosts: '{{ target_env }}'
   gather_facts: True
   any_errors_fatal: true
   roles:
     - role: deploy
       tags:
         - deploy
       become: yes
       become_user: tomcat
       become_method: sudo
```

Please if someone can advice. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You already answered your own question. You can split the inventory, run with `-e target_env=prod-1`, check if it works and then run the same thing but with `-e target_env=prod-2`.

Comment: @toydarian I have thought about this but I don't think it will work because I am using ```group_vars``` where I have a file name ```prod.yml``` which contains all the configurations for production environment. If i use like this ```-e target_env=prod-1``` then how will it pick up those configurations?

Comment: Easy, make `prod-1` and `prod-2` children of a group `prod` and assign the group vars to the group `prod` so all hosts in `prod-1` and `prod-2` will pick them up.

Comment: @toydarian ok will this work?

```
[prod-1]
prod-1-myapp
prod-2-myapp
prod-3-myapp

[prod-2]
prod-4-myapp
prod-5-myapp
prod-6-myapp

[prod:children]
prod-1
prod-2
```

Comment: yes, check out my answer and follow up if it is unclear in some point

Comment: @toydarian yes I have looked into it and seems to be working for me. I just have one issue. So my playbook during it's execution copies the configuration files using jinja templates from a particular path ```/home/ansible/ansible/ansible-myapp-5.80.0-05/config/application/{{target_env}}/general.properties```

Here {{target_env}} is populated from the user input parameter and the actual path will contain ```prod``` folder. But now since I am passing ```prod_one``` as target_env it will fail.

Comment: use `.../application/{{config_loc}}/general.properties` instead and set the variable `config_loc=prod` for the group `prod` in your group variables.

Answer (score 3):

> Q: *"Deploy on 3 nodes and test it. If the test is successful then go for the remaining 3 nodes."*  (using group_vars **prod**.yml / **preprod**.yml)

A: Make `prod_1` and `prod_2` the [children](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups) of `prod`. For example

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[prod_1]
prod-1-myapp
prod-2-myapp
prod-3-myapp

[prod_2]
prod-4-myapp
prod-5-myapp
prod-6-myapp

[prod:children]
prod_1
prod_2

[preprod]
preprod-cn-p1
```

Then deploy group `prod_1`. If all is right deploy `prod_2`. For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- import_playbook: myapp-main.yml
  vars:
    target_env: prod_1

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - fail:
        msg: Test prod_1 failed
      when: prod_1_failed|default(false)|bool

- import_playbook: myapp-main.yml
  vars:
    target_env: prod_2

shell> cat myapp-main.yml
- hosts: '{{ target_env }}'
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Deploy {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [prod_1] ****

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [prod-2-myapp] => {
    "msg": "Deploy prod-2-myapp"
}
ok: [prod-1-myapp] => {
    "msg": "Deploy prod-1-myapp"
}
ok: [prod-3-myapp] => {
    "msg": "Deploy prod-3-myapp"
}

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [fail] ****
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY [prod_2] ****

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [prod-4-myapp] => {
    "msg": "Deploy prod-4-myapp"
}
ok: [prod-5-myapp] => {
    "msg": "Deploy prod-5-myapp"
}
ok: [prod-6-myapp] => {
    "msg": "Deploy prod-6-myapp"
}
```

---

The group `prod_2` shouldn't be deployed when `prod_1` fails. Test it. For example

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -e "prod_1_failed=True"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [prod_1] ****

  ...

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [fail] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Test prod_1 failed"}

  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically are almost there.
Split the inventory, run with `-e target_env=prod-1`, check if it works and then run the same thing but with `-e target_env=prod-2`.

To share your group variables, your inventory should look like this:

```
[prod_1]
prod-1-myapp
prod-2-myapp
prod-3-myapp

[prod_2]
prod-4-myapp
prod-5-myapp
prod-6-myapp

[preprod]
preprod-cn-p1

[prod:children]
prod_1
prod_2
```

All group variables that should be shared on all six prod servers need to be assigned to the group `prod`.

Comment: Fix the syntax. prod-1 and prod-2 are not valid names.

Comment: @VladimirBotka that's correct yes. I should use underscores. I have changed it to prod_one and prod_two